# Add custom NSViewController with Nib to view

Tags: swift, nsview, nsviewcontroller

Background info: I have an `NSTableView` with custom `NSView` cells (`PreviewCell : NSView`) and would like to add such a `PreviewCell` (with its custom nib) as subview outside of the table as well.

Project setup:

```
AppDelegate  [displays MasterviewController]
MasterViewController : NSViewController
MasterViewController.xib  [contains table with Preview.xib rows]

Preview : NSViewController
Preview.xib  [contains PreviewCell]
PreviewCell : NSView
```

The table is displayed correctly. I'm having trouble however with adding the `Preview` controller with Nib to the `MasterViewController`.

```
// in viewDidLoad()
var pinned = Preview(nibName: "Preview", bundle: nil)
self.view.addSubview(pinned!.view)
pinned!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 600.0, height: 120.0)
```

The view is not visible at all. If I instead add it to the contentView of the window (in `AppDelegate`), it works perfectly:

```
// in applicationDidFinishLaunching()
var pinned = Preview(nibName: "Preview", bundle: nil)
self.window.contentView.addSubview(pinned!.view)
pinned!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600.0, height: 120.0)
```

Adding just the `PreviewCell` in `MasterViewController` (so the Nib is not used) works as well:

```
var pinned = PreviewCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.table.rowHeight))
self.view.addSubview(pinned)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, setting an `setAutoresizingMask` on the subview is a bad idea.
Once the autoresizing is removed, the subview (in my case `Preview`) was displayed correctly.